# How can I install the terminal emulator from elementary OS Freya on ubuntu 15.04 Vivid?

Tags: 15.04, elementary

I like the elementary OS terminal emulator quite a lot and I'd love to have it on my main machine, which is running Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid.

Is it possible without compromising Ubuntu's stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that , you can install it by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-terminal
```

#### Another possible solution.

download the source code from https://launchpadlibrarian.net/203448637/pantheon-terminal-0.3.1.1.tgz

Now extract the compressed package:

```
  tar xf pantheon-terminal-0.3.1.1.tgz
```

To compile it:

```
  cd pantheon-terminal-0.3.1.1
  mkdir build
  cd build/
  cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
  make
```

To install it:

```
  cd build/
  sudo make install
```

Comment: I have added more commands. And I think, the latest `cd` command is not necessary.