# Terminal with pointer support (non-arrow keys)

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a terminal emulator in which you can select where to edit with mouse, as in, if you click somewhere in a line you can type at that place (to correct typos)?

Comment: I often make mistakes and would rather just point and click at place I'd like to edit the command. Im unclear if pantheon-terminal has that, but it says it has natural copy/paste so I imagine that involves pointer support. I haven't found a way to install it yet, are there extensions of gnome terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Could you please [edit] your question so other readers may see it right away instead of overlooking it buried in the comments? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pantheon terminal from elementary os, with tabs and more.

Install with compiler (package within ppa is not found):
[How can I install the terminal emulator from elementary OS Freya on ubuntu 15.04 Vivid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631199/how-can-i-install-the-terminal-emulator-from-elementary-os-freya-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Install without compiler (configuring for compilation may be dangerous):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/889655/how-to-install-pantheon-terminal